# PathGeometry FillContains not working as expected

Tags: wpf, hittest, pathgeometry

I have a simple rectangular `PathGeometry` and want to test if the point is inside the `PathGeometry`. The obvious way is to call `FillContains` but it doesn't work as expected. There is also an overload function which has a `tolerance` parameter, although by adjusting the `tolerance` to high values `FillContains` may return `true` but due to the given tolerance calling `FillContains` on other geometries may also return `true`.

So I wrote this extension method to have a correct `FillContains` for this specific rectangular `PathGemoetry`:

```
    public static bool Contains(this PathGeometry geo, Point pt)
    {
        var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(geo.Figures.ToString(), @"M(\d*.\d*),(\d*.\d*)L(\d*.\d*),(\d*.\d*) (\d*.\d*),(\d*.\d*) (\d*.\d*),(\d*.\d*)z");

        float ulx = float.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        float uly = float.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);

        float urx = float.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
        float ury = float.Parse(match.Groups[4].Value);

        float lrx = float.Parse(match.Groups[5].Value);
        float lry = float.Parse(match.Groups[6].Value);

        float llx = float.Parse(match.Groups[7].Value);
        float lly = float.Parse(match.Groups[8].Value);

        Rect rect = new Rect(ulx, uly, urx - ulx, lly - uly);

        return rect.Contains(pt);
    }
```

And the result for a sample:

```
// Point: {188.981887817383,507.910125732422}
// Region: M188.759994506836,501.910003662109L216.580001831055,501.910003662109 216.580001831055,511.910003662109 188.759994506836,511.910003662109z

// returns false
var test1 = region.FillContains(pt);

// returns true
var test2  = region.Contains(pt);
```

Since I have lots of such `PathGemoetry` objects then is there any better implementation of mine for faster hit testing or is there anything I missed while using `FillContains` resulting in unexpected result?

**Edit**

Just noticed that my `PathGeometry` had a Transform applied to it which result in point not fit inside.

I fixed it by using this to bypass the `Transform` in hit-testing:

```
PathGeometry.Parse(region.Figures.ToString()).FillContains(pt)
```

Comment: FillContains works for me with your test data. How do you actually create the PathGeometry from your Region data? In XAML it would produce a StreamGeometry, not a PathGeometry.

Comment: @Clemens, silly mistake, there is a `Transform` applied to the geometry, look at my edit

Comment: Maybe more efficient: `region.FillContains(region.Transform.Transform(pt))`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(Visual reference,  Point point)
```

[VisualTreeHelper.HitTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608752(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Hit Testing Using Geometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748343(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the same problem, I wrote the following functions:

```
public static Drawing? GeometryHitTest( DrawingGroup drawingGroup, Point point )
{
    if( drawingGroup.Transform != null )
        point = drawingGroup.Transform.Inverse!.Transform( point );
    for( int i = drawingGroup.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        Drawing? found = GeometryHitTest( drawingGroup.Children[i], point );
        if( found != null )
            return found;
    }
    return null;
}

public static Drawing? GeometryHitTest( Drawing drawing, Point point ) //
    => drawing switch
    {
        DrawingGroup group => GeometryHitTest( group, point ),
        GeometryDrawing geometryDrawing => GeometryHitTest( geometryDrawing, point ),
        GlyphRunDrawing geometryDrawing => GeometryHitTest( geometryDrawing, point ),
        _ => throw new Exception()
    };

private static readonly Pen hitTestPen = new( new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Red ), 5 );

public static Drawing? GeometryHitTest( GeometryDrawing geometryDrawing, Point point ) //
    => geometryDrawing.Geometry.FillContains( point ) || //
            geometryDrawing.Geometry.StrokeContains( hitTestPen, point ) ?
                geometryDrawing : null;

public static Drawing? GeometryHitTest( GlyphRunDrawing glyphRunDrawing, Point point ) //
    => glyphRunDrawing.Bounds.Contains( point ) ? glyphRunDrawing : null;
```

Call them like this:

```
DrawingGroup drawingGroup = VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing( visual ) ?? throw new Exception();
Drawing? drawing = GeometryHitTest( drawingGroup, point );
```

The important bits are as follows:

- Follow transforms with the following lines:

  ```
  if( drawingGroup.Transform != null )
      point = drawingGroup.Transform.Inverse!.Transform( point );
  ```

  If there is a possibility that you have transforms attached not only to DrawingGroup but also to GeometryDrawing and GlyphRunDrawing, then you should add similar code in the respective functions that handle individual drawing types.
- Visit children from the top of the z-order towards the bottom with the following line:

  ```
  for( int i = drawingGroup.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
  ```

Another thing worth noting is the `hitTestPen`. I had to declare this otherwise the hit-testing would never succeed on the stroke of a geometry. I am not sure why. I am still researching this to find some solution better than a hard-coded pen-width of 5.